# Why does index/match not work?

Tags: excel

In the attached spreadhsheet, I am trying a straight forward index match with data in another sheet. I cannot figure out why the formula only works for some entries and returns mismatches for others. Does anybody have any thoughts?

Many thanks!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kkjs5gshg58wze/CN%202014%20dataset%20list_edited.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why some of your cells are returning incorrect values is, because you're missing the match_type parameter of the MATCH function.

See this page for more information: [Office Online: MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca)

Because this parameter is omitted, Excel assumes that the 'Identifier' column in the 'Categories' sheet is sorted ascending, which leads to wrong search results in your case.

To solve this, add 0 (zero) to your MATCH function. This forces Excel to look for an exact match:

```
MATCH('Sheet1 (selected)'!C2;Categories!$B$2:$B$715)
```

change to

```
MATCH('Sheet1 (selected)'!C2;Categories!$B$2:$B$715;0)
```

Comment: Oh, many thanks! I added the 0 after a closing parenthesis, that was the mistake.